# How do I formulate a query to return the elements of an inner array in an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

In my browser Console, my **db.Collection.find("CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc").fetch()** returns a cursor with an **object**, and an **array** called **viewStatisticsArray**.

Find below a demonstration of the returned cursor:

```
_id: "CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc"
DatePosted: Wed Feb 15 2017 15:10:50 GMT+0300 (EAT)
createdBy: "Mr. Walkings"
viewStatisticsArray: Array[2]
```

When the **viewStatisticsArray** is clicked it shows two **Objects** with two elements: **nrOfViews** and **statsDate**.

It is the value of these elements that are of interest to me.

I have tried

```
db.Collection.find({"CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc"}).fetch().map(function(u) {
   console.log("Array: " + u.viewStatisticsArray); // Array: [object Object],[object Object]
   console.log("Number of Viewers: " + .viewStatisticsArray.nrOfViews); // Number of Viewers: undefined
   console.log("Stats Date: " + u.viewStatisticsArray.statsDate); // Stats Date: undefined      

return u.viewStatisticsArray
});
```

Oddly enough the `return u.viewStatisticsArray` returns the **Array[2]**.

How do I formulate a query to return a cursor with the inner **elements** of the **viewStatisticsArray** Array?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: could you provide a sample return value needed

Comment: @collision Certainly! I would like the return value to be an Object (in the browser console), when clicked it should expand to this

nrOfViews: 3126
statsDate: "Wed Mar 08 2017 13:17:44 GMT+0300 (EAT)"

Comment: @collision also if you look @ my initial post, u.viewStatisticsArray.nrOfViews should yield: 3126 while u.viewStatisticsArray.statsDate should yield: Wed Feb 15 2017 15:10:50 GMT+0300 (EAT) and not undefined as currently is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having trouble is because you are trying to access each index of the `viewStatisticsArray` as if it was an object.

```
u.viewStatisticsArray.statsDate
```

However, `viewStatisticsArray` is an array that contains 2 objects.  So if you want to get those values, you must iterate over the array like this.

```
db.Collection.find({"CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc"}).fetch().map(function(u) {
  console.log("Array: " + u.viewStatisticsArray); // Array: [object Object],[object Object]

  u.viewStatisticsArray.forEach(function(e, i) {
    console.log("Number of Viewers - index " + i ": " + e.nrOfViews);
    console.log("Stats Date - index " + i ": " + e.statsDate);
  });
});
```

Because your document field is an array, there is no way to iterate over the elements in the array with a mongodb cursor.  A mongodb cursor only iterates over documents in a collection.  Just use regular javascript to iterate over a field in a document that is an array (as I demonstrated above).

Lastly, it sounds like even though the `viewStatisticsArray` is an array of objects, based on your question, it sounds like you might only care about the last index in the array (which is probably the latest date view counts were calculated).  In that case you can do something like this to get that single object.

```
var latestStats = db.Collection.find({"CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc"}).fetch().pop().viewStatisticsArray.pop();
```